# non www redirect combined with https

Tags: .htaccess, https

I need 2 redirects.  The first is any request which is not https should be https.  The second is any non www should be www.  Below, the https one works, but the second one does not, and tacks on the original url.  I need both of these to work in unison

```
# Redirect non https to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# redirect non www to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When the they are both enabled, the second one duplicates the http_host twice in the url.

What I need is for mysite.com to redirect to https://www.mysite.com as well as http://www.mysite.com to redirect to https://www.mysite.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:  This worked after clearing cache.